# a great idea in Bootlegger Outpost

Tags: world-of-warcraft

any hints on doing this quest, I am in Bootlegger outpost trying to do the "a great idea " quest, i threw the bait but did not get any response from the swarmers, what an I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

To catch one of the bugs, go all the way down into The Gaping Chasm. There are ramps leading down on either side of Bootlegger Outpost.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I got it, you have to go to the edge of the pit and look down.